# How to catch 401 error using fetch method of javascript

Tags: javascript, api

I need to catch error 401 Code of response so that I can retry after getting a new token from token endpoint. I am using fetch method get data from API.

```
   const request: Request = new Request(url.toString(), {
        headers: this.defaultRequestHeaders,
        method: "get",
        mode: "cors"
    });

   const headers: Headers = new Headers({
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    });

   fetch(request)
        .then(function(response)
         {
          ///Logic code
         })
        .catch(function(error)
        {
          ///if status code 401. Need help here
        });
```

Comment: This is very broad. There are no specifics here? Is it an XMLHttpRequest? We can't help you if all you provide is a quickly scribbled map on a piece of paper with a `Is Treasure Here?` question.

Comment: Try to get the property  error.status

Comment: I have added more Code @somethinghere if this will help you.

Comment: If I understand correctly from the docs, an `error` will not be thrown if the server returns a valid message, of which `401` is one, so try `.then(message => if( response.status === 401 ){ ... respond to the status code... })`.

Comment: you beat me to it, although replace `message` with `response` - you can also check `response.ok` which determins if the status is in the range 200-299.

Comment: @somethinghere when the request is unsuccessful, it isn't falling in '.then' clause.

Comment: @Noface ok then How to check it is 401 or some other error

Comment: @VikrantSingh What are you talking about? A successful request is in `then`, and a succesfull request that returned `401` will still be in the `then` clause. `catch` is used for certain errors, but as far as I can read in the dos thats not the case for a status code.

Comment: @somethinghere bro, i have checked in Fiddler, I am getting 401 status code but it is not going in a .catch block.

Comment: @VikrantSingh _Nobody is saying it is going into the catch block_, the `catch` block is for when an actual error occurs - like nothing at all is returned or there's a security issue. A 401 status is simple a 'Yes, we completed this request, and it told us '401'', So the 401 is a valid response and goes into the `then`, _bro_.

Comment: This might be the case with other but my code is going inside .catch block, this why I am asking this question here otherwise I already resolve it on my end. @somethinghere , other option I have to go with jquery

Comment: Then just separate out the code into a function you call in the `catch` and the `then` block. So `function catchError( error ){ console.log( error ); } request.then(response => { if( !response.ok ){ return catchError( response ); } }).catch( catchError )`, that way you can do the same response even if the request was valid but its outcome was not.

Comment: @somethinghere Actually, Tried that one also, Anyway let other see the question if I get answer I will share with you guys. Thanks

Comment: @VikrantSingh did it not work then? We are trying to help but all we get is 'I dont get it' and 'Catch block something'. Describe your issue in more detail and clarify any questions raised by the people trying to help you and your problem can be resolved.

Comment: If you are using axios then this method will be helpfull to catch 401 status:

```axios.post('/endpoint').then(...).catch(function (error) {
       console.log(error.response.status) //401
       console.log(error.response.data.error) // Please Authenticate
})```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Because `401` is actually a valid response to a request to a server, it will execute your valid response regardless. Only if security issues occur, or if the server is unresponsive or simply not available will the `catch` clause be used. Just think of it like trying to talk to somebody. Even if they say "I am currently not available" or "I don't have that information", your conversation was still *successful*. Only if a security guy comes in between you and stops you from talking to the recipient, or if the recipient is *dead*, will there be an actual failure in conversation and will you need to respond to that using a `catch`.

Just separate out your error handling code so you can handle it in instances that the request was successful, but does not have the desired outcome, *as well* as when an actual error is being thrown:

```
function catchError( error ){

    console.log( error );

}

request.then(response => {

    if( !response.ok ){

        catchError( response );

    } else {

        ... Act on a successful response here ...

    }

}).catch( catchError );
```

I am using the `response.ok` suggested by @Noface in the comments, as it makes sense, but you could check for only the `response.status === 401` if you want to.

Comment: didn't work, it just a refactor of code, Already tried that one.

Comment: @VikrantSingh It is not just a 'refactor' of your code, you keep asking the same thing: how do I handle a 401 response in my `catch` and the answer is simple: it _will not automatically go into your catch_ because it is a valid response. So please, please, be clearer in what issue you are trying to solve in that case.

Comment: I think you are getting me wrong, I just want to catch 401 error code if occurs, whether in .catch block or in .then block.

Comment: @VikrantSingh There are two answers explaining this already, you `catch` such an error by checking the status code of a successful request.

Answer (score 32):

You can check the status and if it's not 200 (ok) throw an error

```
 fetch("some-url")
    .then(function(response)
     {
      if(response.status!==200)
       {
          throw new Error(response.status)
       }
     })
    .catch(function(error)
    {
      ///if status code 401...
    });
```

Comment: If the HTTP response is of status 401, the callback function for the `catch` method will not get invoked; instead, the callback function of the `then` method will be invoked, with `response.status === 401`.

Comment: I don't completely agree with throwing an error when the http request was successful.  401 isn't even a server error, simply unauthorized.  Would be better to check the response code and fork your logic IMHO.

Comment: In many case, other than 200 is ok, mainly 201, but some redirections may occur one day (worst case, in a conference for example)

Answer (score 11):

**You can try this**

```
fetch(request)
  .then(function(response) {
    if (response.status === 401) {
      // do what you need to do here
    }
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
        console.log('DO WHAT YOU WANT')
});
```

Answer (score 8):

You can check the `status` of the response in `then`:

```
fetch(request)
  .then(function(response) {
    if (response.status === 401) {
      // do what you need to do here
    }
  })
  .catch(function(error) {});
```

Comment: if the request is unsuccessful then it is going inside.then

Comment: I can see in fiddler it is 401.

Comment: @VikrantSingh you are very unclear, criticising people but not providing any useful reason as to why. A successful request that returns `status 401` will still be inside the `then` handler, so I don't see the issue. Please provide an answer yourself if you are so sure, or provide some quality comments to at least help people debug the issue.

Comment: in case of 401 execution goes into `then` and status can be checked, check this fiddle https://codepen.io/dariospadoni/pen/MGWQxO

Answer (score 5):

```
fetch(url,{
            method: 'GET',
            headers,
            body: JSON.stringify(aData)
        }).then(response => {
            if(response.ok){
                return response.json();
            }

            return Promise.reject(response);
        }).catch(e => {
            if(e.status === 401){
                // here you are able to do what you need
                // refresh token ..., logout the user ...
                console.log(e);
            }

            return Promise.reject(e.json());
        });
```

Comment: `throw new Error(response.status)` is better than `Promise.reject(response)`: in a long chain of actually using the JSON long before the `.catch()` in typical situations many things can go wrong and throw errors. Your `if(e.status === 401){` assumes that errors will be of the not-even-an-error type "response", making the code too fragile.

Comment: I ended up with `return response.ok && response.json() || (e = new Error(\`${ response.status } ${ response.statusText }\`), e.response = response, throw e);`

Answer (score 1):

```
(function () {
var originalFetch = fetch;
fetch = function() {
    return originalFetch.apply(this, arguments).then(function(data) {
        someFunctionToDoSomething();
        return data;
    });
};})();
```

source 
[Can one use the Fetch API as a Request Interceptor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42578452/can-one-use-the-fetch-api-as-a-request-interceptor)

Answer (score -4):

When you want to...

```
catch (error) {
  console.dir(error) // error.response contains your response
}
```