# HTTP POST with authentication

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, http

I'm attempting to make a POST request from React with the following code to authenticate myself:

```
var username = "myUsername";
var password = "myPassword";
const requestOptions = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Basic '+ btoa(username + ":" + password)
    }
};
fetch('/api/tokens', requestOptions).then(res => res.json()).catch(alert("error"));
```

However, when I fail to authenticate, the frontend (browser) opens a dialog box inviting me to login with a username and password (error 401). How do I avoid such box to appear? I'd like the `catch` block to handle this, and it seems like the box is appearing even before `then` and `catch` are executed.

Thanks

Comment: Why are you sending the username/password in two places in the request?? Surely both are not required by the server?

Comment: BTW I suspect https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49902417/how-to-catch-401-error-using-fetch-method-of-javascript is going to be relevant to your question.

Comment: My bad, the user username/password isn't needed in body. But it doesn't change the fact that I still have the issue.

Comment: Check the link I've just posted above, it seems like an identical situation

Comment: Thanks, but as I said: the dialog box to login appears before `then` and `catch` blocks. I tried the solution in the link you gave me, but still doesn't work.

Comment: How are you triggering this JS code? Are you certain the fetch code is definitely what's causing it - e.g. it could be a regular form submit action which hasn't been suppressed or something. Have you used the JS debugger to step through?

Comment: I trigger it by sending a username/password via a form. And the submit goes right when the authentication succeed. I have the same issue as [this link](https://www.voidcanvas.com/how-to-disable-browsers-default-login-prompt-on-401-response/) except that it's in React, but this page didn't help for my issue.

Comment: Ok but that isn't specifically what I asked you

Comment: Apologies! So I trigger the JS code by filling a form with username + password. Yes I debugged, and the `fetch('/api/tokens', requestOptions)` part is where the error happens: that function sends the request to the backend, then if the login fails, the backend detects the 401 error and the same `fetch` function opens the dialog box. If I click "Cancel" in the login box, the console throws error 401, but until the box is opened, nothing happens in the console. Am I answering your question? Let me know if not. Thanks!

Comment: Ok so there's no possibility that a non-ajax, standard postback request is happening at the same time or anything like that?